Terminate the local powershell session when an interactive psremote session is closed
I have a jumphost from which people can log in to remote computers without knowing the passwords to remote computers.
I can create a remote session using following:
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName target1 -credential domain\username
Enter-PSSession $session
So when a user comes in i can hand them this session logged in so they can only access the remote system. But when they exit this remote session, they will fall back to my jumphost. I don't want this to happen and would rather have the session completely killed.
Can someone suggest how can i achieve this ?
I was thinking of solving this using events, so that when my $session.State changes to "Closed" instead of "Opened".
Is this possible to achieve ? I would be glad, if someone can help to point in the right direction
